# Extracting Pure Javascript from NodeJS project

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend

So, I have some homemade "modules" (made by somebody else) that look like:

```
var lodash= require('lodash');

var regexp = require('../lib/regexp.js');

module.exports = function(input) {
      (...)
}
```

I'm starting npm server and using it on some test page, but I'd want to extract it as pure javascript and then use it in other project without npm. Is that possible / achievable easily?

e.g I'd want to use that

```
module.exports = function(input)
```

as just `function("input");` in my other "not-complex" project.

I really want to avoid analyzing that code because it's really huge and would require hours to spend on it.

Comment: Look into running it through webpack - see "authoring libraries".

Comment: @Luca Can I just straight replace every e.g require with "<script src="path.js"></script>" and it's gonna work as require?

Comment: @UbuntuCore —No. Definitely not.